# Uncaught NotFoundError: An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, wrapall

Can't really descripe why this is not working.

I do have JS-Object controlling some data and each controlls also an HTML-Object.
That objects are stored in an Array. I do that a couple of times in many projects, but now it comes to an error while using jQuery's "wrapAll".

Here is the jsfiddle, that should be the best description: http://bit.ly/17ilvDe

Please: I have no Idea whats going on, help me :)

Thanks for reading and thanks for each reply.

Comment: it is because you are creating an array of jQuery objects and trying to create a jQuery object using the the array.. jQuery does not support this model

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't create a jQuery object using a array like that... one possible solution is

```
var elements = $();
$(items).each(function(){
    elements = elements.add(this.Item);
});
elements.wrapAll("<div class='subpage' />");
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5PtRR/)

Comment: Now you've wrapped `items` in a jQuery object it does. +1

Comment: LOVELEY, thanks man, you made my day. I allready thought that what I described was my fault :)